# Swing component for Olap analysis

Tags: java, swing, olap, pivot-table

We're creating a desktop application which will use OLAP server to perform analysis. I'm searching for a Swing component which can provide functionality similar to JPivot. We need to:

- Be able to add cube's dimension as a row/column
- Retrieve data from cube and display it
- Expand/collapse hierarchies (aka slice&dice)

Also JPalo is a good showcase, still it's a Web solution.
[demo](http://www.jpalo.com/en/palo_pivot.php?sent=yes&option%5b%5d=OpenApp&option%5b%5d=ViewTabs&option%5b%5d=AutoLogin&option%5b%5d=AutoUser&option%5b%5d=OpenView1&option%5b%5d=Toolbar1&option%5b%5d=HorizonalAxis1&option%5b%5d=Save1&option%5b%5d=POV1&option%5b%5d=VerticalAxis1&option%5b%5d=Toolbar3&option%5b%5d=HorizonalAxis3&option%5b%5d=POV3&option%5b%5d=VerticalAxis3#pivot)

We've considered few solutions:

- JRubik. Project is outdated and is a standalone application with Mondrian OLAP server embedded, it can't work with remote XMLA sources from scratch. We consider forking the project and rewriting to our needs
- OpenSwing pivot table/JIDE pivot table. There are 2 pivot table components available in network, so we were considering to build our own solution around this components. Anyway, either of them didn't work for us, as both take flat model and do all aggregations inside swing code. Instead, we want to make all aggregations on OLAP side and our swing component should just display it.
- La Azada. It's a another all-in-one application similar to JRubit, built on top of Eclipse RCP. It contains functionality we need, but depends on SWT and Eclipse RCP, so it might be too much effort to embed it into existing Swing application.
- Build our own solution. This is the last option we consider, but it may happen that we will chose this one. In that case, we want to simplify our just as much as possible, so if there is any Swing component with collapsible rows and columns, which may be adopted to connect to XMLA, please let me know.

At this moment we're not happy with neither of proposed solutions, so I would like hear ideas and suggestions from the community. Let me know if question is unclear, so I will try to explain things better. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're developing your own solution, I'd strongly advise using Olap4J

Answer (score 2):

May be this can help
http://java-sl.com/envelope.html

Comment: I had a look on it and looks like it has same drawback as OpenSwing and Jide components: it takes flat model and converts it on the fly to grouped table. I don't see how I can fill this table from OLAP model with expand/collapse support.

Answer (score 1):

We are developing our own product for the last few years.
It is a Swing Pivot Table solution, built on top of JTable, 100% Swing.
We are in the process of writing the manual and javadoc.
It works both with a flat model and data originating from an OLAP cube, using the olap4j library.

You can see a demo here:
[www.scientific.gr/pivot-demo.jnlp](http://www.scientific.gr/pivot-demo.jnlp)

I updated the demo with a more recent version. Maybe it has something to do with the jre version.

Comment: From decsription - it's really nice and would fit our needs, but I can't start a demo. 

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.sciapp.pivot.olap.i.i
 at com.sciapp.pivot.olap.b.a$a.getTreeCellRendererComponent(Unknown Source)

Comment: Yeah, this version works, it looks nice. Does this product have a website? How are you going to distribute - is it freeware? Open source? What license? Thanks

Comment: It is a commercial product. Go to www.citra-tech.com for more info.

Comment: Finally it is released under the name Citra Pivot. You can follow the link below for more information.

http://www.citra-tech.com/products/pivot.html

Answer (score 0):

Another one free simple Java swing component https://github.com/aristsoft/jpivot to visualize the data in multidimentional view.
It designed just to show the data, so it don't doing the data aggregation any kind itself.